# Unable to Run XQuery and Define Datasource with XQuery plugin in PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, xquery

I have PhpStorm (built on the IntelliJ platform).

I've installed the [IntelliJ XQuery Support plugin](http://ligasgr.github.io/intellij-xquery/)

I would like to be able to:

- Define multiple data sources for running your xquery code
- Run my main module

These features are apparently possible using IntelliJ IDE

While the plugin installs on PhpStorm, I have been unable to perform these tasks.

The author does give the disclaimer "... IntelliJ Idea may have some features which others [IntelliJ platform based IDEs] won't."

Can someone confirm that in fact these features are not available when using the plugin in PhpStorm and in fact I need IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can install and use the plugin in IntelliJ IDEA, when using webstorm I can't run or configure any data source. So yes I can confirm that they are not available at the moment.

Comment: I would also suggest opening a ticket in the plugin github, so that can be fixed.

Comment: I also just realized you said Phpstorm and I tried it on Webstorm, but I believe it won't matter anyway. This must be broken for everything else.